# requireJS in a reporting tool - need to understand standard behavior

Tags: requirejs

I have to use a reporting tool (IBM Cognos analytics), which provides the ability to inserts custom scripts in HTML reports created by this reporting tool. So, we are supposed to be able to reference JS libraries like jQuery, jQueryUI, and work with them, etc..
This functionality in the reporting tool is official, and it is stated that they are using requirejs to handle this.
The model of code we need to respect in this case (from IBM "api") is the following:

```
define(['https://our_site/someFolder/someResource.js'], function() {

    /*
    A) - Here, I would expected that any code writtne here is executed only when "someResource.js" has been loaded
   */

function monModule() { };

monModule.prototype.setData= function() { 
    /*
            B) - some code here
            */
};      

monModule.prototype.draw= function(o) { 
    /*
            C) -  some code here
            */
};

return myObject;});
```

My questions are the following:

1) My current understanding of the behavior within a "define" block is that the JS code will be executed only once the resources mentioned in the "define" instruction are loaded/available. Is it correct?
In the example above, the part mentioned in A) or C) would be "evaluated" / executed only when the resource "someResource.js" is loaded. Do I understand correctly?

2) the RequireJs library used by IBM Cognos analytics shows the following:

/** vim: et:ts=4:sw=4:sts=4
 * @license RequireJS 2.1.14 Copyright (c) 2010-2014, The Dojo Foundation All Rights Reserved.
 * Available via the MIT or new BSD license.
 * see: http://github.com/jrburke/requirejs for details
 */

Can I assume then that the RequireJS library used by IBM Cognos analytics is the "common" / "standard" and not a derived one, and so that all functionalities and behavior of RequireJS should be available in IBM Cognos analytics?

I'm asking all this because we are facing issues where some piece of JS code seems to be executed before the resource is loaded; we get error like ' "$" doesn't exist ..etc..'.

Any help / advice is welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). The callback of `define()` is only executed once, to define your module.So in your example, only A) will be executed, but B) and C) are the code of methods in the prototype of `monModule`

Here are steps which RequireJS is doing under the hood when you execute `define()` function:

1. It loads async module's dependencies
2. When dependencies are loaded, it executes the callback, injecting loaded dependencies as arguments. The callback should returns a value which is defined module.
3. It stores internally the returned value, so when other module require just defined module it will be injected as argument.

2) You can calculate md5 checksum for that file and validate it against the "official" RequireJS library

About errors you are get. Maybe you need to setup shim to make sure that jQuery is loaded before the module which needs jQuery?

Comment: Hi Damian, Thanks for your swift answer. You say " So in your example, only A)", ok, fine. But is A) being executed only once "someResource.js", or is it independent? I'm going to try this shim technique, and will see the checksum stuff. Thanks!

Comment: yes, thanks!, it is clear and helpful. Now I have to find a way to understand why the behavior is not as expected when we are using it from the reporting tool. I'll check if I can implement this shim, etc.. (again, due to the particular context of this reporting tool). I'll come back to tell which solution I found, but I fear that I'm going to need either a support from the reporting tool or a external point of view.